# Connecting two Macbook pros with thunderbolt cable

Tags: macos, macbook, macbook-pro, cable, external-display

I am trying to find a way to connect a macbook pro to another macbook pro as a second screen with a thunderbolt to thunderbolt cable (or differently). I am not able to find online if that's doable (its not working for me anyway). It seems like Apple provides some info about it but only when the "external" machine is an iMac. Appreciate any help with the topic. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this with Thunderbolt, and what you've seen from Apple is probably using a Macbook Pro and an Apple Cinema Display (which looks like an iMac).

What you can do however, is use an application like [Synergy](http://synergy-foss.org/) to seamlessly control both computers with one keyboard and mouse. This will only allow you to control both computers individually however.